# VDHL: when else clause inside case clause

Tags: syntax, mips, vhdl, modelsim, mips32

I need to implement a slt instruction from the MIPS32.

The operation itself is simple. The output is 1 if the input_1 is smaller then the input_2 else is 0.

From the MIPS Specification:

```
if GPR[rs] < GPR[rt] then
GPR[rd] ← 0(GPRLEN-1) || 1
else
GPR[rd] ← 0(GPRLEN)
endif
```

Because i decode the funct in my alu-stage i can directly perform the computation. So far so good, but i dont understand, why vcom does only accept the first option. The second option always produce a "Illegal sequential statement.".

The second question is, if the equation is true, does the output has to be "0...01" or rather "111..111"?

```
case funct is
*
*
*
--first option
when "101010" => if (signed(s_alu_input_1) < signed(s_alu_input_2)) then
                s_alu_result(0) <= '1';
                s_alu_result(31 downto 1) <= (others => '0');
                else 
                    s_alu_result <= (others => '0');
                end if;
--second option
when "101010" => s_alu_result(0) <= '1' when signed(s_alu_input_1) < signed(s_alu_input_2) else
                                '0';
                 s_alu_result(31 downto 1) <= (others => '0');
*
*
*
end case;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VHDL, you are not allowed to use the `when` statement in a `process`.  You need to be using `if`.

This line:

```
s_alu_result(0) <= '1' when signed(s_alu_input_1) < signed(s_alu_input_2) else
                            '0';
```

`when` in VHDL can only be used in combinational assignments outside of a process.

Comment: To avoid confusion in the future it is worth noting that the restriction on the use of `when else` and `with select` inside a process was removed in VHDL-2008.